# Код не проходит определенный тест

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решаю эту [задачу](http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=692). Не проходит 5-ый тест, немного менял код программы и проверял количество чисел, которые он находит в промежутку от 0 до 10000, и программа нашла мне 14 чисел степени двоек типа: 1 2 4 8 16 и т.д, что если я не ошибаюсь правильно. Подскажите в чем может быть ошибка, что система не пропускает на 5-ом тесте. Спасибо!

Вот мой код:

```
a = list(bin(int(input())))[2:]
b = a.count('1')
print('YES' if b == 1 else 'NO')
```

Comment: Приведите текст задачи в самом вопросе с помощью кнопки "править". Тогда в случае неработоспособности ссылки вопрос будет иметь смысл

Comment: Возможно, единица не считается подходящим числом (примеры чисел начинаются с 2).

Comment: `>>> [i for i in range(10000) if bin(i).count('1') == 1]`
`[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192]` вроде бы правильные степени

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if ( num ) and ( not (num & (num - 1)) )`

где: `if ( num ) - True`, если `num` число не равное нулю;

`if ( not (num & (num - 1)) ) - True`, если `(num & (num - 1))` равно нулю.

`&` - Побитовое И

```
num = int(input())
# 1024
print('YES' if num and not num & (num - 1) else 'NO')
# YES

num = int(input())
# 102
print('YES' if num and not num & (num - 1) else 'NO')
# NO
```

Ваше решение тоже должно работать, если правильно вводить данные:

```
def func(num):
    a = list(bin(num))[2:]
    b = a.count('1')
    return b

[ i for i in range(10000) if func(i) == 1 ]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192]
```

Comment: Твое решение прошло, как ты думаешь почему мой код не проходит?

Comment: и если не трудно можешь немного пояснить условие в принте

Comment: я постарался ответить на ваши вопросы. См. мой ответ.